# I need help making a scroll button

Tags: javascript, css, button, scroll

I want to make a scroll button like the one on this wesbite: 
https://codepad.co/snippet/scroll-down-button-css
I have copied all the code, but when I open the website in my browser the button doesnt work, even though i copied everything word for word. I dont know enough JS to figure this out myself. thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use jquery library file locally or with cdn address. without jquery scroll function will not work.

jquery cdn path is:- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js

simply copy this script tag and use before your function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    body {
  background-color: #000;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  
}
section.ok{
  background-color: #555;
}

p{
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.scroll-down {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.scroll-down:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    left: calc(50% - 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <p>SCROLL DOWN CSS</p>
        <a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true"></a>
        </section>
        <section class="ok">
        <p>OK SCROLL !</p>
        </section>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>   
        <script>
         $(function() {
    $('.scroll-down').click (function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section.ok').offset().top }, 'slow');
      return false;
    });
  });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. I have only  just learned about HTML and CSS, not any javascript. I thought I could just copy it and link it like an CSS file. I will try and figure out what this jQuery lib is now. thanks.

Comment: Wish you all the best !!!

Comment: I did as you said and it worked for me. But after uploading it to github, the button doesnt work anymore!

Answer (score 0):

u said u copied everything word by word ,, but is,t not working on your laptop just the example code .

or you are testing it on existing site ??

in Case 1 > be sure inlucding the jQuery lib inside the page to make sure all the function work

in Case 2 > You have to change the direction of the scroll as u can see

```
{scrollTop: $('section.ok').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

like u can see the scroll will be directed to the Section with Class with name "ok"

so be sure what is ur case and wish u luck <3

Comment: Please check this page out: [answer]

Comment: Ok. I have only  just learned about HTML and CSS, not any javascript. I thought I could just copy it and link it like an CSS file. I will try and figure out what this jQuery lib is now. thanks.
edit: Case 1

Comment: @rala i did check it thanks , but can u be more clear what do u mean , thanks

Comment: I included jQuery lib and it worked. But after uploading it to github, the button doesnt work anymore.

Comment: it dosent work anymore on your device or online ?

Comment: It works on my device (if I open my index.html on desktop). but it doesnt work online!